# How To Calculate the values for an HMM?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-models, markov

I need help understanding and solving two questions from HMM. Please see these [matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ0Dy.png),
where 
 the hidden states are **H = happy and S = sad**. 
**Pi** is the initial probability table 
 
**P(x[t] | x[t-1])** is the transition table and 
**p(y[t] | x[t])** is the emission table

How do I comprehend:
If at time t-1 we have **p(x[t−1] = H | y[1:t−1]) = 1**, what are the values of **p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1])**? 
What about
**p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1]; y[t] = Play)**?

I do not know how to comprehend and therefore calculate these questions.
How could I calculate these values with matrix calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Given that data, let's answer:
`p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1])`, then `p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1]; y[t] = Play)` should be quite intuitive. But please note that so is not a site for doing your homework.

Anyhow, when dealing with Markov chains, keep one thing in mind: History doesn't matter! So no matter what your previous observations were, your current observation 
(`y`) will only depend on the current state `x[t]`. (don't tell that your history teacher that, she will try to make you repeat the class, as it was in my case).

So: `p(x[t−1] = H | y[1:t−1]) = 1` is the same as saying that the previous state was Happy (`H`). That "given" y[1:t−1] doesn't give us any info.
OK, what do we know about the `p(x[t]|x[t-1]=H)` ? Well, the first row, in the first matrix tells you what the probability of transition from one state to another is.

Now we can answer your first question:
`p(x[t] = H) = p(x[t] = H | x[t-1] = H)*p(x[t-1] = H) + p(x[t] = H | x[t-1] = S)*p(x[t-1] = S)`
If the previous formula is too much, Hint: `p(x[t] = H)` is the unconditional probability of she being happy today. 
Since we already know that   `p(x[t-1] = H) =1` (she was happy yesterday), it means that she was definitely NOT sad yesterday: `p(x[t-1] = S) =0 =>` 
`p(x[t] = H) = p(x[t] = H | x[t-1] = H)`, and using the first matrix, you get: `0.6`

How about?
`p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1]; y[t] = Play)` , apply "History doesn't matter rule", and you get:
`p(x[t] = H | y[1:t−1]; y[t] = Play) = p(x[t] = H | y[t] = Play)`
Here's another hint if you want to do it yourself: `p(x[t] = H) =0.6` cause we already answered that! You also know that: `p(x[t] = H) + p(x[t] = S) = 1` (cause she can only be Happy or Sad, right?)

Now apply the Bayesian rule (which I know is non-intuitive, but there are many good videos on youtube explaining also the intuition behind) and you can write your question like this:
`p(x[t] = H | y[t] = Play) = (p(y[t] = Play| x[t] = H) * p(x[t] = H))/p(y[t] = Play)`

But then you might say: hey, I already am observing she is playing, you might be tempted to substitute that with 1, not so fast, because in Math, this `p(y[t] = Play)` means the unconditional probability.

`p(y[t] = Play) = p(x[t] = H)*p(y[t] = Play|x[t] = H) + p(x[t] = S)*p(y[t] = Play|x[t] = S)`

So :
`p(x[t] = H | y[t] = Play) = (p(y[t] = Play| x[t] = H) * p(x[t] = H))/(p(x[t] = H)*p(y[t] = Play|x[t] = H) + p(x[t] = S)*p(y[t] = Play|x[t] = S))`

Now you have no unknowns, Substitute from the tables and calculate.